Compatiility of Postgres 14.9 with Centos 6.9
I have postgres 12.18 installed on my Centos 6.9 OS (I know it's too old). I want to upgrade to postgres 14.9, is it possible ?
I am trying to install postgres 14 but getting lot of issues.
sudo yum install postgresql14-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl, replace, versionlock
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
pgdg12                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/14/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: pgdg14. Please verify its path and try again

Please help
I want to upgrade my postgres version to 14.9 from 12.18 on centos 6.9
I tried to run commands at https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/ but no luck.
Getting lots of errors.

Do you have access to the link they provide in the error-message? Is it related/helpful? (I can't read it because it is subscriber-only)

If you look at the postgres 14 repo they don't have binaries for rhel6. The closest they have is 14 for rhel7. You could try those, although that probably won't go smoothly either. Or compile from source.

As described on the download page, you should install the latest repository RPM:
sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

But really, upgrade your operating system (and then rebuild all indexes on strings).
